# Rotate HDMI screen by 90 degrees on Yocto image on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gtk, yocto

I have embedded system with touch screen connected via HDMI for video and USB for touch. On Yocto image, I have python app using GTK library and Xserver to render GUI on screen. Everything works fine.
But now, for design reasons, I have to mount screen in portrait orientation, so I need to rotate image 90 degrees. I have found, that `xrandr -o 1` should do that, but I have got error "Can't open display". I wasn't able to find any solution on the internet.
Is there something I'm missing, or is there some other way to achive this?
B.R.
Michal

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland? Also, how do you run the command? Through the GUI, or using serial/ssh/init-script/similar?

Comment: I'm not sure, what is difference between X11 and Wayland. Both of these therms are present on lot of places in my image.  
I start my app with "/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/myapp.py"

Comment: xrandr works only with x11. You can check your session type by `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. If it gives you x11, then possibly you are not specifying the `DISPLAY` environment variable before running it

Comment: Variable $XDG_SESSION_TYPE is empty. I had display connected to HDMI1. When I tried to connect it to HDMI0, xrandr start to work as expected. There was also issue witch touch input, which wasn't affected by xrandr, but I had expect that. It's something I can fix.